# Reducing lists in R to match another list.

Tags: r, list, match

Suppose I have a dataframe 'H', like so

```
C1  C2  
a   1
b   1
c   2
d   3
e   4
f   4
g   5
```

and a list X (as.factor) that goes

```
"1" "2" "4"
```

Using the match command,

```
X2=H[match(X,H$C2),]
```

only reduces H to three rows and only one instance of each element of X is present (a,c,e). What command should I employ to reduce H to X such that all instances of elements found in X are present (i.e, the reduced table should contain a,b,c,e,f)?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> H[H$C2 %in% X,]
  C1 C2
1  a  1
2  b  1
3  c  2
5  e  4
6  f  4
```